# Struggling to remove values from one vector using another larger vector iteratively in R (sample.int invalid first argument error)

Tags: r, statistics

I'm working on a simulation of the Monty Hall problem in a stats class using R. The gist of the problem is that there are three doors, and behind one is a prize. The other two have goats. After the player has selected their door, the game show host reveals one of the doors that contains a goat and gives the player an opportunity to switch from their original choice. We're supposed to show that the player has a 2/3 chance of winning if they switch doors and a 1/3 chance if they stick with their original selection using 10000 experiments.

It's important to note that my professor wants us to randomize both the door containing the prize and the door the player originally chooses, which is where my problem arises.

I've successfully finished the simulation where the player sticks with their original choice. Now I'm struggling to create the function that determines which door the game show host reveals so the player can make a new choice that excludes their original choice *and* the door the host reveals. As of right now, here is my function to reveal a door:

```
## Function to open a door
revealed_door = function(initial_choice, car_door, all_doors){
  ## if-else to determine which doors can be revealed and reveal one
  ifelse(car_door == initial_choice, sample(setdiff(all_doors, initial_choice), 1),
         setdiff(all_doors, c(initial_choice, car_door)))
}
```

`car_door` is a vector of length 10000; each element is randomly sampled from 1:3.

`initial_choice` is a vector of length 10000; each element is randomly sampled from 1:3.

`all_doors` is a vector of length 3: c(1,2,3).

When I call the function later, I get the following error:

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid first argument

I'm (clearly) not using `sample.int`, so I'm not sure why this error is coming up.

Additionally, instead of `setdiff`, which is the most common solution I saw when I researched on my own, I have tried:

```
ifelse(car_door == initial_choice, sample(all_doors[-initial_choice], 1),
       all_doors[-c(initial_choice, car_door)])
```

I also got the following error at some point, but I can't for the life of me remember what I did to replicate it:

> only 0’s may be mixed with negative subscripts

Finally, at some point I managed to remove all errors but the reveal vector filled with `NA` values, so obviously the ending probability ended up being 0.

Here is my most recent code block to deal with switching, in case that helps:

```
switch_wins = 0
## Switch doors
reveal = revealed_door(initial_choice, car_door, all_doors)
new_choice = all_doors[-c(reveal, initial_choice)]
## Count wins
ifelse(car_door == new_choice, switch_wins + 1, switch_wins)
total_switch_wins = sum(switch_wins)
## Divide wins by n to calculate probability
switch_win_prob = total_switch_wins / 10000
print(switch_win_prob)
```

However, I believe my issue stems from the fact that I don't know how to remove values from `all_doors` using `initial_choice` iteratively in my `reveal_door` function, but that is as far as I got in my debugging process. I would not have this issue if I were allowed to keep `initial_choice` constant, hence my comment above.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `ifelse(car_door == initial_choice, sample(all_doors[-which(all_doors==initial_choice)], 1),all_doors[-which(all_doors %in% c(initial_choice, car_door))])`.

Comment: This gave me the sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid first argument error again :(

Comment: Using the initial data created by Wimpel, this might work for you as well `apply(df,1,\(x) ifelse(x[1] == x[2], sample(all_doors[-which(all_doors==x[1])], 1),all_doors[-which(all_doors %in% c(x[1], x[2]))]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach

```
#initialise
n = 10000
all_doors <- 1:3
df <- data.frame(
  car_door = sample(all_doors, n, replace = TRUE),
  initial_choice = sample(all_doors, n, replace = TRUE))

#calculations
df$opened_door <- mapply( function(x,y) ifelse(x == y, 
                             sample(setdiff(all_doors, x), 1), 
                             setdiff(all_doors, c(x , y))), 
                           x = df$car_door, y = df$initial_choice)

df$door_if_switched <- mapply( function(x,y) setdiff(all_doors, c(x, y)), 
                               x = df$opened_door, y = df$initial_choice)
# determine win
df$won_keep_initial <- ifelse(df$car_door == df$initial_choice, TRUE, FALSE)
df$won_after_switch  <- ifelse(df$car_door == df$door_if_switched, TRUE, FALSE)

# see results
sum(df$won_keep_initial) / n
sum(df$won_after_switch) / n
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, though I did change a few things to integrate it with my original code. I appreciate your help :)